# Android Firebase runTransaction operation for two different Firebase Database Location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just a quick message to ask you if you know how to do a **runTransaction()** operation at two different locations in a Firebase Database?
Indeed, I have got a View Counter that needs to be updated at two different siblings Nodes.
I have read this post, but as the Author pointed out, this is **very inefficient** : [Create a transaction to update multiple places in Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669302/create-a-transaction-to-update-multiple-places-in-firebase-database)

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction read-and-updates a single location in the database. There is no support for multi-location transactions at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Frank !! Hopefully something to come in a near Future. PS: I Love your #AskFirebase videos, keep up with the great work !!